# Plot the outcome of glm()

Tags: r, plot, regression, logistic-regression, glm

I am an R beginner (first semester - we us this programme for univariate statistics) and currently struggling with plotting the outcome of my glm(). I read quite a few threads and help files on the internet, but I have 2 problems: 1) I don't understand the advice because it is too advanced or 2) I understand the advice but when I replicate the code, it doesn't work.

I think I am close to the solution, but my curve doesn't work how it is supposed to. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
new.data<-data.frame(x=rnorm(50,0,1), y=c("yes", "no")) 
mock_model<-glm(y~x, data=new.data, family=binomial) 
x1<-seq(min(new.data$x), max(new.data$x), 0.01) 
y1<-predict(mock_model, list(x=x1), type="response") 
plot(new.data$x, new.data$y, xlab="numeric var", ylab="binary var") 
points(x1, y1)
```

I am new to coding and this platform, so apologies in advance if the information I have provided is not sufficient.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data. Without some data to run the code we can't for sure see what you are seeing so it's unclear what the problem is.

Comment: Oh right, makes sense! Judging from the link a small data frame with variables similar to my data should be fine? 

`new.data<-data.frame(x=rnorm(50,0,1), y=c("yes", "no"))
mock_model<-glm(y~x, data=new.data, family=binomial)
x1<-seq(min(new.data$x), max(new.data$x), 0.01)
y1<-predict(mock_model, list(x=x1), type="response")
plot(new.data$x, new.data$y, xlab="numeric var", ylab="binary var")
points(x1, y1)`

Comment: Edit this information into your original question. Comments cannot be properly formatted and it really should have been there from the start.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using `mtcars` and the `ggplot2` package. The syntax of `ggplot2` works roughly like this: You begin a plot with the `ggplot()` command, within which you can (but don't have to) define aesthetics (the `aes()` option), which include selection of axis variables, but can also contain options to change the visuals, like colors, linewidths etc. If you define the axis variables within `ggplot()`, don't forget to put the `data` assignment (see example below) outside of `aes()`.

Afterwards, you add layers of geoms to plot specific things, like data points with `geom_point()`, lines with `geom_line()` or a lot of other fun things. When you want to use the variables and data assigned in the `ggplot()` command, just leave the `geom` empty (apart from any visual `aes()` options you want to use for that specific `geom`). However, you can define new data and variables for a `geom`, for example to use different data sources in the same plot.

```
data(mtcars)

model_shift <- glm(am ~ mpg, data = mtcars, family = 'binomial')
x <- seq(min(mtcars$mpg), max(mtcars$mpg), .1)
y <- predict(model_shift, list(mpg = x), type = 'response')
plot_data <- data.frame(mpg = x, am = y)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = am), data = plot_data) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Or with a line instead of points:

```
ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = am), data = plot_data) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

To get a glimpse of the seemingly endless possibilities of `ggplot2`, have a look at [these 'Top 50' ggplot2 visualizations](http://r-statistics.co/Top50-Ggplot2-Visualizations-MasterList-R-Code.html). To learn the package-specific language, see [this tutorial](http://tutorials.iq.harvard.edu/R/Rgraphics/Rgraphics.html) or check your university's library for Hadley Wickham's book `ggplot2: elegant graphics for data analysis`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining all these basics to me. When I tried with ggplot2 before it did not work for some reason, but with your step-by-step guide it did! Thank you, again.